# How can i display the site url instead of the ip address?

Tags: ee2, ee1, ee

I am working in a project in EE that was previously done by somebody else. The problem is that in the image source link , it is showing as:

```
<img src="http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX/images/news/image.jpg">
```

but what I want is, is that to be like this:

```
<img src="http://myexample.com/images/news/image.jpg">
```

What might be the solution?

P.S. I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an image loaded from a file upload location, adjust the the file upload preference url to be what you need.  Looks like the previous developer forgot to do this when they launched the site.  Search your templates and css files, it may also be hardcoded in there somewhere as well.

Comment: Also, make sure it isn't hard coded in the template you are using.

Comment: I think I said that...........

Comment: It's Friday morning, give me a break lol